# How can I pause a Bootstrap Carousel on hover and resume it on mouse-out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I have a Bootstrap Carousel on my website.

When the user hovers over an element `#formcontainer`, I'd like to pause the carousel. And when I hover off, I'd like to continue the cycle of the carousel. The first part works fine with the following code, but not the second. Can someone assist?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1200,
        pause: "hover"
    });

    $('#formcontainer').hover(function(){
        $("#myCarousel4").carousel('pause');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [carousel `cycle`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#carouselcycle) method on `mouseleave` event

```
$('#formcontainer').hover(function(){
   $("#myCarousel4").carousel('pause');
},function(){
   $("#myCarousel4").carousel('cycle');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function has [an implementation that takes two arguments](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerIn-handlerOut): a hover *in* handler and a hover *out* handler:

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
    // handler in
}, function() {
    // handler out
});
```

When you pass it [just one argument](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerInOut), the function you give it handles *both* the in and out events, so you're pausing it on both mouse enter and mouse out.

You need to pass it separate handlers:

```
$('#myCarousel4').hover(function() {
    $(this).carousel('pause');
}, function() {
    $(this).carousel('cycle');
});
```

Note that we can use `this` to refer to the carousel rather than rewriting its ID. Inside jQuery event handlers, `this` always refers to the object you bound the event to when possible.

Comment: strange that this isn't the most upvoted answer when it's clearly the most complete..

Answer (score 1):

This will work!

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        pause: 'hover'
    });

}); }(jQuery));
```